# Paypal returning back to my site when payment is done

Tags: jsp, paypal

I am using this code to pass my values to **paypal**.
Now my problem is that, that after the payment is complete I should be on my page so that I can manipulate some of the things like I should save the **Token** for future reference and so. Again I comes back to my page when **user implicitly clicks** the link formed in the page of **paypal** after the **payment is done**.But here the problem is I cant just rely on user to click or do so.I want that it should be implicit without any user intervention.
Thanks in advance,please shed some light.....

```
<% 

    String apiusername="USERNAME";
    String apipassword="PASSWORD";

    String truePath="http://localhost:8080/Befundo/xtraFiles/paypal/paypalResponse.jsp";
    String falsePath="http://localhost:8080/PaypalGS/paypalResponseCancel.jsp";

    String itemName="Computer Laptop";
    String quantity="2";
    String amount="100";
%>


<body >
<form name="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
     <input type="text" name="business" value="<%=apiusername %>" />
     <input type="text" name="password" value="<%=apipassword %>" />
     <input type="text" name="custom" value="1123" />
     <input type="text" name="item_name" value="<%=itemName%>" />
     <input type="text" name="amount" value="<%=amount%>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<%=quantity %>" />
     <input type="text" name="rm" value="1" />
     <input type="text" name="return" value="<%=truePath %>" />
     <input type="text" name="cancel_return" value="<%=falsePath %>" />
     <input type="text" name="cert_id" value="API Singature" />
     <input type='submit' value='Pay'>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can do this by configuring the auto return url in paypal profile.**

*To set up Auto Return:*

```
1. Log in and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
2. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
3. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
4. Enter the Return URL.
```

When you'll log into merchant's profile, you'll see:

[image: preferences1]

and after clicking website payment preferences link, you'll see:

[image: preferences2]

Here you can give the autoreturn url.

This will enable the auto return , which means that after payment being successful, paypal will automatically redirect to your website, without user intervention.

Here's paypal guide for enabling auto return: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside

Hope this helps.

Comment: because I am not getting any **link** saying the options you specified

Comment: Yes, Ofcourse.. :-) You can do this in sandbox and configure it by logging into seller's account.

Comment: Where is the *Website Payment Preferences* link this is the page I am getting after clicking *Profile* tab::

http://db.tt/FAFELBhY

Comment: ah, this is not the seller's account. When you will log into seller's account it will be shown under selling preferences section.

Comment: Just upated the answer.. pLease see if it helps. :-)